# QGIS z value, MSL vs HAE

Tags: qgis, gps, elevation

I have been using Qfield to collect field locations (x,y & z) with a GNSS receiver. I can correct for the antennae height within the app (trimble mobile manager), so that that when QGIS records the Z (using $Z) it records the ground elevation (HAE) in meters (note if I use (@position_coordinate) it records the antennae elevation in meters without the correction for instrument height). On the GNSS receiver app it shows me the HAE and the MSL elevations in feet as I navigate the field.

I am interested in the MSL in feet. I have used some simple functions to transform the HAE from meters to feet. But I wonder if there a different way to code the Z-value so that it pulls the MSL elevation in feet straight from the receiver rather than the HAE in meters? With the data being able to be displayed, it seems you should be able to simply pull that value in rather than go through all the steps. But what is the correct code to do so?

Currently, as I said, I record the $Z (HAE in meters), then convert to feet, then using NOAA site, determine the N value to then get the correct MSL in feet for each location. I've also just taken screen shots at each site to record the z value in MSL feet, but that is very inefficient as well.

Is there a different way to auto-fill the Z for MSL rather than HAE?

Comment: What GPS device are you using?

Comment: I use DA2 Trimble